# How can I force an HTML page to render slowly?

Tags: dom, uiwebview, html-parsing, html-rendering

Although this question is a general DOM rendering question, let me tell you where I am coming from.

I am working on an app which uses UIWebView in iOS to load HTML pages.  A peculiarity of UIWebView is that it calls webViewDidFinishLoad when the frame is loaded, which can be before the DOMContentLoaded event fires.  I wrote some Javascript which returns the readyState, and the app calls this code and waits until it is either "interactive" or "complete", and then continues.  Life is good.

However, now my boss (Hi!) wants me to include a unit test which tests whether or not we can successfully wait for the ready state to change.  This means I need to create a reliably slow rendering HTML page, preferably without any outside resources.

Just doing a busy wait in some Javascript in the head does not work, since Javascript is single threaded, and my code for testing the ready state will not run until after my busy wait is done.  A fellow programmer suggested that I use a web worker to get around this single threading issue, but I am not sure how that would help me.

I was intrigued by the description of the role of document.write in the rendering process described in [this description of browser rendering](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#The_parsing_algorithm) and [this tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/document-write), but I am not sure that would do me any more good than simply linking to a lot of slow loading files.

My basic problem is that I would like to have a page which I know will reliably render in the 100ms to 1000ms range.  It has to work on other developers' machines and into the future.  When my test machine or network gets twice as fast as it is today, I want this test to still work.

What approach can I use to control how long the DOM takes to render?

Comment: Would something like [Network Link Conditioner](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) help?